# FBSDKMessageDialog for iOS doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:APPSTORE_URL_MAIN];
content.contentTitle = INVITE_TITLE;
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:INVITE_IMG_URL];
content.contentDescription = INVITE_TEXT;

[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

If the Facebook Messenger app is closed, this just opens the app and does nothing else.

Works fine is the FB Messenger app is working in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by [Facebook Developers.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1479622972343972/)

Comment: The issue is still exist on iPad running iOS9.1 with FB Messenger version 47.0